# What is the term for the big background that the canvas lies on in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The title says it all.

**What is the dark part that extends beyond the image called?**

[image: Dark background Photoshop interface]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the **Document Window**

Answer (score 4):

[Alex's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/70669/408) is kind of right, but the area specifically is called the *canvas* and the canvas makes up the document window. You can see this when you are choosing a custom color for it, Photoshop calls it the `Custom Canvas Color` -- though I'll be the first to admit that it's kind of a misleading name considering the image itself also can be called a canvas. Sometimes people specify by calling the area extending beyond the image the **background canvas**.

You can see people refer to it as such as well when you google how to [change the canvas background color](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=change%20canvas%20color%20photoshop) and [here's one from the Photo SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20564/how-do-i-change-appearance-of-canvas-background-in-photoshop-workspace)

[image]

**EDIT**

Since there seems to be some confusion, the term Photoshop chose is "Canvas" but because the image area itself can be, and sometimes is referred to as a canvas, saying "Background canvas" is more appropriate.

Comment: I refer to that area as the "background canvas" since "canvas" alone often refers to the size of the document (as in the Image > Canvas Size dialog box).

Comment: Right, seems like Adobe is confused about it themselves. Like ispaany says, the canvas size is always the same as the image size, yet they call the background color the canvas color.

Comment: @ispaany Right. I was sure to mention that in my answer. I too prefer that term.

Comment: @Larry Lawless, yup! I think it's a weird term, but it does seem to be the "official" term :)

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop CC has helped us define terms that were already used in illustrator before. It's not all set in stone, as Johannes was saying, but **the "image"** as you called it **is now called an artboard.**

That being said, I don't like calling the background area the "document window" because "window" has a connotation of the entire application.

Final answer: **The background area behind the artboard should either be called Canvas or Canvas Background**.

You can see the canvas can actually be painted on, and sits on what I further dubbed the cavas background. 
[image]

Comment: What is now an artboard in CC has always been called the canves (i.e Change Canvas Size...) so I don't think calling it the canvas is very good. Canvas background makes more sense though I guess.

Comment: It's true that it used to be called canvas, but I like that it's now more consistent with the way Illustrator and InDesign work, with artboards/pages as foreground on a larger canvas and I think that holding on to its old terminology is more of a hindrance than a help.

Comment: Since I use CS6 and regularly "Change Canvas Size" I wouldn't call it a hindrance ;)

Comment: True dat. I sometimes forget about older versions of adobe when I make my comments, which is probably not the best.

Comment: We don't draw pixels on it though. I think the canvas is the painting area, the black background should be called the table or wall.

Comment: @LarryLawless actually you **can** work within the canvas and outside of artboards.

Comment: In Illustrator yes, but can you do that somehow in Photoshop? I can't paint on the black background.

Comment: @Peacockerie I'm not sure what exactly your answer adds. I disagree that the image area is called "artboard" because Photoshop CC has [something separate](http://i.imgur.com/OCMOkaW.png) from the regular images/canvases that are specifically called artboards, so I don't think the term I used was necessarily incorrect though I didn't pick that word ("image") deliberately, I simply wanted to avoid the word "canvas" again. And I did mention in my answer that they can be called background canvas to specify which one you're talking about.

Comment: The CANVAS does look like a piece of art hanging on a dark WALL though.

Comment: @johannes What is called an artboard in CC is the same as the default "artboard" that opens, except that there can be more than one. It seems like the term would apply across the board. Also, what my answer specifies is that when using multiple artboards there is a distinction between the canvas (editable area behind artboards) and the canvas background (uneditable area behind canvas.)